# how to upcast an immutable list

Tags: java, casting, immutablelist

I have written a class `ImmutableList<T>` which is similar to `ArrayList<T>` except it does not have any add or remove operations.

Now let's say we have a class `Animal` and a subclass `Cat`.

I am aware that a cast from `List<Cat>` to `List<Animal>` is not safe, because it would allow one to insert a `Dog` object into a list of cats.

This problem does not exist with immutable lists, because one cannot insert anything into an immutable list anyway:

```
ImmutableList<Cat> cats = ImmutableList.of(berlioz, marie, toulouse);
ImmutableList<Animal> animals = cats;
```

is safe, but the compiler won't allow it.

Therefore I would like to add a method to `ImmutableList` that helps me to perform a safe cast, maybe like this

```
ImmutableList<Cat> cats = ImmutableList.of(berlioz, marie, toulouse);
ImmutableList<Animal> animals = cats.upcast();
```

or even

```
ImmutableList<Cat> cats = ImmutableList.of(berlioz, marie, toulouse);
ImmutableList<Animal> animals = cats.upcast(Animal.class);
```

I have tried

```
 public <S super T> ImmutableList<S> upcast() {
   return (ImmutableList) this;
 }
```

but that does not compile (you cannot say `<S super T>` here, only `<S extends T>`).

The desired method should satisfy some requirements

1. It must not allow unsafe casts, such as from `ImmutableList<Animal>` to `ImmutableList<Cat>` 
2. It must be efficient, i.e. not copy the list
3. preferably not use reflection

Is it possible to write such a method? Failing that, how would you address the problem?

Comment: Why not just use ImmutableList<? extends Animal> and ImmutableList<? extends Cat>?

Comment: @JBNizet: I hesitate to do this for the following reason. I would then have to use ImmutableList<? extends Animal> as the return type of a method that computes a List of cats and returns it as a list of animals. I have an active SonarLint rule that strongly recommends not using wildcard types as return types.